# Find command incorrect results with days filter

Tags: ubuntu, find

I am trying to find all files modified before march 6 in a directory with thousands of files.

I executed the following commands in the PWD where I want to find files.

```
find -mtime +47 > /root/file_005.log
```

or

```
find -mtime +48 > /root/file_006.log
```

or

```
find -mtime +49 > /root/file_007.log
```

The problem is no matter what date filter(47,48.49.50...) is used in the find command I keep getting files with a modified date between March 8 -12 in the results.

This is the output of `stat`on one of the problem files:

```
Device: 16h/22d Inode: 17 Links: 1 
Access: (0666/-rw-rw-rw-) Uid: ( 8506/ UNKNOWN) Gid: ( 5000/ UNKNOWN) 
Access: 2013-04-22 10:08:20.000000000 -0500 
Modify: 2013-03-10 03:10:20.000000000 -0500 
Change: 2013-03-10 03:10:20.000000000 -0500
```

Does anyone have an idea what may be causing files that were modified after March 6 to appear in the results?

**EDIT #1**

- Q: Is this a NTFS mounted filesystem or EXT3/4?
- A: No its not. This is a drive mounted on my UNIX box using sshfs.

Comment: Your question is unclear, `-mtime +47` run today (04/22) will find files that were created before March 6th. Is your problem that you find files modified before **March 6th** or between **March 8 -12**? It _should_ find files modified before the 6th.

Comment: The question is quite clear "I am trying to find all files modified before march 6" ...."I keep getting files with a modified date between March 8 -12 in the results."

Comment: That is the results includes files modified before March 6 and files between March  8 to 12. The results should only include files modified before March 6

Comment: OK, I am asking because the last sentence in your question reads `Does anyone have an idea what may be causing files that were modified before March 6 to appear in the results?`. I guess you meant _after_. Could you post the output of `stat` on one of the files that is wrongly returned?

Comment: Oh Sorry. I corrected the question.

Comment: Here is stat on a file that showed in the results:
Device: 16h/22d Inode: 17          Links: 1
Access: (0666/-rw-rw-rw-)  Uid: ( 8506/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 5000/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2013-04-22 10:08:20.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2013-03-10 03:10:20.000000000 -0500
Change: 2013-03-10 03:10:20.000000000 -0500

Comment: No its not. This is a drive mounted on my UNIX box using sshfs

Comment: Is the clock correct on that server?

Comment: Can we clean these comments up?

Comment: I see you're using sshfs, what machine are you using FUSE to mount with sshfs to? Is it the same system or another system? If so what OS, etc. is this other machine?